# Only new user of User node database are retrieving but i want to display the info of current log in user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code to retrieve currently log in user but it give me only the new registered user or the crendential on top of Authentication List  [This is the authentication of my firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJeNq.png)

[This is the exported database json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9EPb.png) and it always display kahdb@gmail.com (info of Noway) user but i`m using different user credentials.

```
 public void showAllUserData() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    String userKey = user.getUid();
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(userKey).exists()) {
                    String nameString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                    String studNumString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userStudNo").getValue(String.class);
                    String emailString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userEmail").getValue(String.class);
                    String passString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userPass").getValue(String.class);

                    editname.setText(nameString);
                    editstudentNo.setText(studNumString);
                    editEmail.setText(emailString);
                    editPassword.setText(passString);
                    nameLabel.setText(nameString);
                    studentNoLabel.setText(studNumString);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e("DatabaseError", "Error reading from database: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my complete profile code please help me modify this to get the desired output. I want to display this [Michelle user info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5leJ.png) but only Alvarez is displaying

```
 package com.example.practice;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.practice.databinding.ActivityProfileBinding;
import com.example.practice.databinding.ActivityScannerBinding;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Profile extends Drawable {

    TextView nameLabel, studentNoLabel, editname, editstudentNo, editEmail, editPassword;
    Button update;
    ActivityProfileBinding activityProfileBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityProfileBinding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityProfileBinding.getRoot());
        allocateActivityTitle("Attendance Scanner");

        editname = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editstudentNo = findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentNo);
        editEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        nameLabel = findViewById(R.id.nameLabel);
        studentNoLabel = findViewById(R.id.studentNoLabel);
        update = findViewById(R.id.update);
        
        showAllUserData();
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 passUserData();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showAllUserData() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        String userKey = user.getUid();
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(userKey).exists()) {
                        String nameString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                        String studNumString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userStudNo").getValue(String.class);
                        String emailString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userEmail").getValue(String.class);
                        String passString = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("userPass").getValue(String.class);

                        editname.setText(nameString);
                        editstudentNo.setText(studNumString);
                        editEmail.setText(emailString);
                        editPassword.setText(passString);
                        nameLabel.setText(nameString);
                        studentNoLabel.setText(studNumString);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.e("DatabaseError", "Error reading from database: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    public void passUserData() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            String userKey = user.getUid();
            ref.child(userKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String nameDB = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                        String emailDB = dataSnapshot.child("userEmail").getValue(String.class);
                        String studentNoDB = dataSnapshot.child("userStudNo").getValue(String.class);
                        String pass = dataSnapshot.child("userPass").getValue(String.class);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, editProfile.class);

                        intent.putExtra("userName", nameDB);
                        intent.putExtra("userEmail", emailDB);
                        intent.putExtra("userStudNo", studentNoDB);
                        intent.putExtra("userPass", pass);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are retrieving a list of users, and then using `setText` which would display the last user, that you retrieved in this list. You need to change the database schema to the following:

```
users
  <user-id>
       userName: "michy"
       userStudNo : 1
```

Then you can do:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
 String userKey = user.getUid();

    ref.child(userKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String nameString = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
                String studNumString = dataSnapshot.child("userStudNo").getValue(String.class);

                name.setText("" + nameString);
                studNum.setText("" + studNumString);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}}
```

You need to get the userId then pass it as an argument to `child()` and then you dont need to loop anymore, you can just get the information for the current user.

Comment: I used your code but it gives me error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Is the user logged in? It would give u null if the user is not authenticated.. are u using firebase auth for authentication?

Comment: i used your code, it is now retrieving data but the current registered user info are always storing event if I log in different user. I updated my code, can you help me solve it to display the user info of currently log in? @Peter